# Azure OCR unable to detect roman character "I" and "II"

Tags: azure, text, computer-vision, ocr

I have this image [image].

I am using Azure Computer Vision API - v2.0,
combination of Recognize Text API(POSt) and Get Recognize Text Operation Result(GET) as mentioned in https://westcentralus.dev.cognitive.microsoft.com/docs/services/5adf991815e1060e6355ad44/operations/587f2c6a154055056008f200. to detect text characters in the image.

Currently it is able to detect all the characters except letter I and II.
Can someone help?

Comment: maybe it is a problem of scale? From left top right, the first `I` seems to me smaller than the second `I`.

Comment: Its unable to detect any of character I. I tried with larger image of 512 x 512 in which this was just a part of, that also didn't returned the character I